# Javascript swap two objects a, b, which way is better?

Tags: javascript, swap

Get 3 ways to swap two objects a and b in js, but not sure if there has any difference between them and which one is better?

1.

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

2.

```
b = [a, a = b][0]
or
b = [a][a = b, 0]
```

3.

```
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Comment: @Xufox I was under the impression that the first *does* create an intermediate array - the right-hand side of an `=` is evaluated before anything is done with the result. No reference to the array remains after destructuring, but I think one *is* created?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, right, it does…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[a,b] = [b,a]; 

b = [a, a = b][0]; // shorthand version
```

ES6 (Firefox and Chrome already support it (Destructuring Assignment Array Matching)): ***But its extremely slow.***

***The temp variable method is slightly faster, and more general and more readable as well***

Comment: what about the Edge?

Answer (score 2):

Define "better"...

Personally - for readability, I'd say the first example.

The second example I could probably follow if I had 2 or 3 whiteboards...the third example should be a capital offense ;)

Comment: the third way was the simplest until 2015 :p

Comment: Yep, but it's 2018 now :) I'd always favor readability whenever possible

Comment: Ronald Reagan :D

Answer (score 0):

IMO, better way would be:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
console.log(a); // 3
console.log(b); // 1
```

Source: [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)